# Python Id reconciliation algorithm

Tags: python, dataframe, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to find the lowest level parent id that is connected to a certain child id.

For example lets say you have the following:

| Parent ID | Child ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 9 | 100 |

This should become the following:

| Parent ID | Child ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 6 |

Note: So think of it as saying 1 is the parent of 3 and 3 is the parent of 5. This means that 1 is the root node of the family tree.  I want to roll up the parent ids to the root of their family tree. Hope this clarifies this for you.

Is there any way to do this in python while also making it efficient for a million records (i.e. I have a data frame that has 1 million rows in it that I need to do this Id reconciliation to)? Thank you so much!

I am trying to figure out how to create the function to do this in python while also making sure the function is as fast as possible.

Comment: Please explain the algorithm for producing the result. It is not clear.

Comment: Yep, I also can't see the rules by which you get from the first table to the second. Also, when you [edit] the question, replace the "python" tag with the "algorithm" tag.

Comment: 1 is not a parent of 4

Comment: 1 is the parent of 3. 3 is the parent of 5. 5 is the parent of 7. 7 is the parent of 8. 8 is the child of 4. 8 is also the parent of 9. And 9 is the parent of 100. All of this is one family tree where the root node is 1.

Comment: Technically both 1 and 4 are roots in the group, equally, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph problem, you can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to solve it:

```
import networkx as nx

# load DataFrame as directed graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Parent ID', target='Child ID',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find the roots (i.e. parents without parents)
roots = {n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0}

# group the connected nodes together
groups = {next(iter(g&roots), list(g)[0]): g
          for g in nx.weakly_connected_components(G)}

# pick one root per group and form the pairs
out = pd.DataFrame([[k, v] for k, s in groups.items()
                    for v in s-{k}],
                   columns=['Parent ID', 'Child ID']
                  ).sort_values(by=['Parent ID', 'Child ID'],
                                ignore_index=True)
```

*NB. note that 1 and 4 are both roots of their group, thus they could both be selected as parent in the final output.*

Output:

```
   Parent ID  Child ID
0          1         3
1          1         4
2          1         5
3          1         7
4          1         8
5          1         9
6          1       100
7          2         6
```

Your graph:

[image]

Comment: I keep getting a StopIteration error for the next(iter(g&roots)) part of the code. Is there a way to fix that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Try: `next(iter(g&roots), list(g)[0])` instead of `next(iter(g&roots))`, you might have circular groups.

Comment: This works but I wanted to ask what if you have a loop on the node. I.E. 1 is connected to 1. Would this be able to deal with that or do you have to make changes to the code.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "*dealing with it*". That wouldn't cause an error.